# Using logparser to parse files of specific age

Tags: logparser

Once again I am attempting to parse through some 12+ .csv files to get an overall sum of fax pages sent. I have created a text file that lists all of the .csv files I wish to parse based on a range of dates...

```
logparser -i:fs "select Path into .\FaxReportNames.txt from *inbound_faxing*.csv where to_string(LastWriteTime,'yyyy-MM-dd') >= '2020-01-01'"  -rtp:-1 -recurse:-1
```

Now I would like to use that list of files in another logparser query to sum the same column in all of the files. The goal is to get a total number of fax pages for that time range. I attempted to use logparser in conjunction with a batch job but that only parsed one file at a time.

```
for /f "skip=2" %%F in (FaxReportNames.txt) do (
    echo %%F
    logparser -i:csv "select sum(NUMPAGES) from '%%F%'"
)
```

I suppose I can take the for loop even further and concatenate all of the files into one large file but that seems just silly to do. Perhaps I am searching wrong but is there some way to parse the files from the list generated and get an overall sum?

I also foresee requests for break downs of the data per month so I will likely be referring to a date column within the files at some point as well...

Comment: Is it a possibility for you to just include all the files in the query via wildcards? For example: `...FROM MyFile_2020-*.csv`

Comment: Use another `FOR /F` command to capture the output of the `LOGPARSER` output. Then you can assign that to an environmental variable really easy. So your inner `FOR` command would look something like: ```FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (`logparser -i:csv "select sum(NUMPAGES) from '%%F%'"`) DO set /a sum+=%%G``` This should work but without seeing the logparser output I can't say for sure.